# In iPhone keyboard appears in the portrait mode rather than the landscape one. Any solution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My keyboard appears in portrait mode when i rotate a single view to landscape.

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
self.view.transform = newTransform;

}

Comment: You are only converting a view to landscape which will not show the keyboard in landscape. it will always show in portrait mode. If you need to do this for a singleViewController then you need to customize it.

Comment: can you plz suggest me any option? how can i customise? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single view controller to support only landscape orientation you should do it the 'Apple way" by implementing

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Remeber to set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES in your plist file

See this link for more details - [Supporting Multiple Interface Orientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)